# Can you autofill numbers going upward?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I know how to autofill numbers going downward. But I'm curious if you can autofill numbers going upward? I'm using Excel 2011 on MacOS X (El Capitan).

It may sound counter-intuitive, but my boss wants to see the newest items in a list on top. But I also number these items, and don't want item the newest item to show up as item #1.

Here's a rough example:
* #5 1/14/16
* #4 1/13/16
* #3 1/12/16
* #2 1/11/16
* #1 1/10/16

Right now, I'm sorting the dates by newest-to-oldest. But how do you sort the item number by highest-to-lowest?

Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually enter #2 above #1 and then select both cells, you can grab the fill handle and fill upward.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the prompt reply! Unfortunately, I'm not seeing the fill handle when I try to fill upward.

Is this a deficiency of the Mac Excel 2011 version vs. Windows?

Comment: I doubt this is a difference between the Windows and Mac versions of Excel, but I do not have a copy of Excel 2011 to confirm this. Just to be clear, you don't see the little black square at the bottom-right-hand corner of the selection? If you do, grab it and drag up through the range you want to fill.

Comment: **EUREKA!**

Because I was looking to autofill upward, I was looking for the black square at the top-right corner of the selection. I didn't realize that I needed to be looking at the bottom-right corner like normal.

And now it's worked perfectly! Thank you, @Excellll. Send me your email address and your next cup of of coffee on me.